# Why does this fail to make my postfix configuration step non-interactive?

Tags: apt, bash, postfix

I have a bash script to automate configuration of new Ubuntu systems.  It works, except that `postfix`'s process installation persists in bringing up a menu-based interface.  I followed the [answer given to this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556385/how-can-i-install-apt-packages-non-interactively) about how to prevent this from happening, yet it *doesn't* work for me, and I have not been able to understand why.  Here is the relevant fragment from the bash script:

```
ubuntu_configure_postfix()
{
    # Set up mail so that daemons can send out mail.

    echo "postfix postfix/mailname string `hostname`.ourdomain.org" | debconf-set-selections
    echo "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type string 'Satellite system'" | debconf-set-selections
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install postfix
    apt-get -y install mailutils
    echo "root: me@ourdomain.org" >> /etc/aliases
    newaliases
}
```

Can someone help me find my mistake?  How can I make the `postfix` installation completely non-interactive?

Answer (score 0):

I'm setting them like this:

`debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type string 'Internet Site'"`