# Something like a -y flag for unattended-upgrades

Tags: upgrade, unattended-upgrades

I've been able to configure automatic security updates with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

Running the above command brings up a configuration page. I only need to hit enter twice and the process is complete.

I'm looking for a way to automate the setup. For example with a`pt-get install` I can use the `-y` flag.

Is there a way I can do this with `unattended-upgrades` so the process can be automated?

Comment: Possibly related [How can I install apt packages non-interactively?](https://askubuntu.com/a/556387/178692) (i.e. probably what you really want to know is how to run `dpkg-reconfigure` non-interactively)

Comment: Unattended-upgrades is enabled by default in 16.04 and newer versions of Ubuntu. Configurations are in /etc/apt/apt.conf . What exactly do you need to configure?

Answer (score 0):

That can be done by adding `noninteractive` to the command:

```shell
dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive unattended-upgrades
```

where the `-f` option in `dpkg-reconfigure` selects which debconf frontend to use (here set to `noninteractive`).