# Terminal auto answer question

Tags: command-line, updates

When I try to update my machine using terminal it ask some questions about should it override the current file or not, or should it continue or not. So my question is how can I make it just to continue and answer yes to everything it asks, coz I dont want to manually answer those questions every time I make an update.

Comment: what command are you using?

Comment: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Look also [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/556385)

Comment: try `sudo apt-get --yes update && sudo apt-get --yes upgrade`

Comment: ah just add that --yes, thanks guys really much appriciated!